# C# accept a value more than once from textbox

Tags: c#

I need to accept more than one value from the same textbox and store it into an arrya . I need something close to the below code  :

```
    string[] countries = new string[3];
    private void accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        countries[0] = textBox1.Text+"  1 ";


        countries[1] = textBox1.Text + "  2 ";

        countries[2] = textBox1.Text + "  3 ";
    }
    private void finish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string coun in countries)
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered " + coun);}


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `?` in your post...

Comment: Do you want the user to enter multiple countries in the textbox and than split the string? how shall the entried be separated? please explain your situation a little more in detail and also what exactly the problem is that you are having with your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

How do you split the different countries?

If you split it on each space you can do it like this:

```
string[] countries = textBox1.Text.Split(null);
```

If that is not a good solution maybe try and explain the expected output.

Comment: "New Zealand" is not two countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a [multiline textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx) and split the input on newlines:

```
var countries = countriesTextBox.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a list? The following code will add the country's name entered in the textbox to the `List<string>` every time you click the accept button.

```
var countries = new List<string>();

private void accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    countries.Add(textBox1.Text);
}

private void finish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string coun in countries)
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered " + coun);
}
```

If you want to allow the user to enter multiple countries at once, the following will work if you put a comma in between each country name when entering them into the textbox:

```
var countries = new List<string>();

private void accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
    countries.AddRange(input);
}

private void finish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string coun in countries)
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered " + coun);
}
```